# CheckStyle: JavaDoc <p> Separator Violations

Tags: java, javadoc, checkstyle

I have the following JavaDoc, with a `<p>` separator but (1) no blank lines and (2) the text after `<p>` continues on the next line, all of which is normal.

```
/**
 * Fetches a list of Org beans based on the provided org code.
 * <p>
 * Note: This also takes care of Parent/Child orgs.
 * 
 * @param org Organization string
 * @return List of Org beans
 * @throws Exception
 */
List<Org> loadOrgs(String org) throws Exception;
```

In CheckStyle, my configuration is [per the spec](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/javadoc/JavadocParagraphCheck.html) to allow full flexibility with `<p>` formatting:

```
    <module name="JavadocParagraph">
        <property name="allowNewlineParagraph" value="true"/>        
    </module>
```

But after refreshing, CheckStyle still reports 2 problems with the `<p>`:

[image]

```
- <p> tag should be preceded with an empty line.
- <p> tag should be placed immediately before the first word, with no space after
```

Any idea how to get rid of both of these?

Comment: http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/javadoc/JavadocParagraphCheck.html "In case of `allowNewlineParagraph` set to `false` the following example will not have any violations:"

Answer (score 0):

In the IntelliJ IDEA 2020, select / highlight the comments in question and reformat it (Shift + Command + L).